# Performing a regression that tests a diminishing return of a variable, how to create model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I'm currently working on a project for school and for this project I need to run a regression that tests if there is a diminishing return for two variables. This is my current model as I am basing it off what I've seen elsewhere online:

```
model2 <- lm(Stability_Change ~ (Total_SSA)^2 + Total_SSA + rpe_agri + Population + (Polity)^2 +  GDPperCap, data = MainDataSet)
summary(model2)
print(model2)
```

In essence, I want to try and see if there is a diminishing effect that security assistance has on the stability of a country. I.E. the more money a country receives, the less effective the aid is (theoretically). I have tried this model and another model:

```
model2 <- lm(Stability_Change ~ Total_SSA + rpe_agri + Population + (Polity)^2 + GDPperCap + (Total_SSA)^2, data = MainDataSet)
summary(model2)
print(model2)
```

I mainly want to ensure I properly make my model so that I don't mess this up as this project is 80% of my grade. Varaibles are:

```
Stability_Change = change in stability of a country in a years time (Dependent)
Total_SSA = total amount of sceurity assistance aid given to a country (Independent)
Control Variables:

rpe_agri = relative political capacity of a country
Population = total population of a country
Polity = Polity Scores measuring how much a country is an autocracy or democracy
GDP_PerCap = GDP per Capita
```

Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Could you show us the two outputs from `summary(model)`?

Comment: @AdriàLuz Hey Adria, Sorry I never saw your comment, I was able to confer with my professor regarding the model, and he helped to steer me in the right direction. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to give each model a different name.

Including the square of Security Assistance is a reasonable approach, if you suspect the relationship will best fit a quadratic curve as opposed to a cubic or some other.

As to how to develop your model "properly":  that may be a much more complex matter than you realize.  In addition, there may not be a single "correct" version.  Moreover, whether to include additional variables such as Polity or its square may be best informed by extra-statistical thinking or evidence.